# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when creating a mask on dataset

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, fiona

i am trying to make a mask on a dataset as follows:

```
out_image, g= rasterio.mask.mask(dataset=NDVIsTIFFAsDataset, shapes=bufferedTreatmentAsGeoJSONInEPSG3857)
```

the value of the `shapes` parameter is shown below in the geojson-section.

when i run the code i get the following error:

```
\lib\site-packages\rasterio\features.py", line 381, in bounds
geom = geometry.get('geometry') or geometry
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

please let me know why i am getting this error and how to fix it.

**geojson**

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[1221264.56231168,6562227.15082514],[1221315.80509721,6562207.93416727],[1221358.89709103,6562186.53372218],[1221396.7734732,6562156.82591229],[1221427.86442239,6562120.04213943],[1221450.88140711,6562077.70706959],[1221464.87058378,6562031.57541617],[1221469.25231334,6561983.5591931],[1221463.84516119,6561935.64845665],[1221451.03320157,6561876.72133815],[1221437.499351,6561834.21019213],[1221416.2532694,6561794.9993198],[1221388.04928194,6561760.48062804],[1221353.88867878,6561731.87942912],[1221314.98416504,6561710.21095959],[1221262.46263963,6561687.15341746],[1221217.71428339,6561672.63384802],[1221170.98407589,6561667.29223627],[1221124.12479244,6561671.34035318],[1221078.99432582,6561684.61771402],[1221037.3820421,6561706.59793706],[1221000.93784983,6561736.40960188],[1220967.63077581,6561769.71530745],[1220937.77563096,6561806.2124051],[1220915.73165029,6561847.92152375],[1220902.37459545,6561893.18594766],[1220898.23519343,6561940.20768535],[1220903.4780329,6561987.11887951],[1220917.89500168,6562032.05600148],[1220940.91352954,6562073.23388361],[1220988.31125791,6562141.13127133],[1221017.08356446,6562175.04831015],[1221051.67866402,6562202.96611529],[1221090.87379923,6562223.89783272],[1221133.28358406,6562237.10354452],[1221177.40897946,6562242.11643575],[1221221.69029076,6562238.75930378],[1221264.56231168,6562227.15082514]]]}
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could create minimal working code (with example data in code) which we could simply copy and run to see problem.

Comment: It seems to be possible if you tell us how the variable bufferedTreatmentAsGeoJSONInEPSG3857 is created.

If there is a geojson you provided, I will convert it to geopandas.GeoDataFrame and insert the geometry of the data frame to process it.